# Query using MPI Reduce in C

Tags: c, for-loop, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to use `MPI_Reduce()` in C to compute a vector called *phi* with *npts* elements. To do that, I have allocated chunks of a long vector (*longvec*), to each process, sum these chunks separately and then sum the partial result of each processor at the end in process 0 to obtain an estimate of each element of phi.

I am getting very silly results... Can anyone tell me what mistake I am making in the code below?

```
double phie[npts];
phitemp = (double*) malloc (nprocs * sizeof(double));    

for (i = 0; i < npts; i++) {
   phitemp[rank] = 0; 
   for (x = rank * 10 + 1; x <= (rank + 1) * 10; x++) {                     
      phitemp[rank] = phitemp[rank] + longvec[x] * vector[i];                             }
   }
   MPI_Reduce(phitemp, & (((double *) phivec)[i]), 1,  MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
}
```

Comment: Please tell us about why the results you are getting are 'silly'.  What are your expected results?  What have you tried?

Comment: Doing the same calculation in Matlab and getting results of a completely different order of magnitude...

Comment: You are assigning to `phitemp[rank]` and then are reducing a single element from the start of the array. Obviously the reduction will use wrong values from all processes except rank `0`. Use a scalar `phitemp` instead.

Comment: what is `phivec`? could you please post minimal code example that compiles (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Thank you very much, @Hristo. That should solve my problem.